# mvn clean compile jib:build failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, jib

so i have been trying to deploy my spring microservices using jib and it has been really fustrating :(
I have been jumping from one issue to another and right now i dont how to get out of this present situation... I have used openjdk 17 alphine and this is the logs i get from my build...

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\weddingapp-main\weddingapp> mvn clean compile jib:build -rf :discovery-service                                                                                               [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] discovery-service                                                  [jar]
[INFO] api-gateway                                                        [jar]
[INFO] wedding                                                            [jar]
[INFO] users                                                              [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< com.slinkdigital:discovery-service >-----------------
[INFO] Building discovery-service 1.0-SNAPSHOT                            [1/4]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ discovery-service ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\xampp\htdocs\weddingapp-main\weddingapp\discovery-service\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ discovery-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ discovery-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\xampp\htdocs\weddingapp-main\weddingapp\discovery-service\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jib-maven-plugin:3.3.0:build (default-cli) @ discovery-service ---
[INFO]
[INFO] Containerizing application to registry.hub.docker.com/davidtega/discovery-service...
[INFO] Using credentials from Maven settings file for registry.hub.docker.com/davidtega/discovery-service
[INFO]
[INFO] Container entrypoint set to [java, -cp, @/app/jib-classpath-file, com.slinkdigital.eureka.DiscoveryServiceApplication]
[WARNING] PATCH https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/davidtega/discovery-service/blobs/uploads/79257277-0299-4f05-90cc-e33f34d3a44a?_state=P1UgMi0NjbwAR3C9mu77RBBM0P2yRJNUC5Qz-wEGppl7Ik5hbWUiOiJkYXZpZHRlZ2EvZGlzY292ZXJ5LXNlcnZpY2UiLCJVVUlEIjoiNzkyNTcyNzctMDI5OS00ZjA1LTkwY2MtZTMzZjM0ZDNhNDRhIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDIyLTEwLTEyVDA0OjMyOjU2Ljg4OTcxNzc4OFoifQ%3D%3D failed and will NOT be retried
[ERROR] I/O error for image [registry.hub.docker.com/davidtega/discovery-service]:
[ERROR]     java.net.SocketException
[ERROR]     An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[INFO] Executing tasks:
[INFO] [=======================       ] 77.8% complete
[INFO] > launching layer pushers
[INFO] > scheduling pushing manifests
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for discovery-service 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] discovery-service .................................. FAILURE [32:57 min]
[INFO] api-gateway ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] wedding ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] users .............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  32:58 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-10-12T06:05:32+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.3.0:build (default-cli) on project discovery-service: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have restarted my pc severally, cleaned up my config.json file and tried every other solution i have seen but its still not working, i will appreciate the assistance... Thanks